# Какова этимология слова «ответственность»?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Как ни странно, этимологические словари (во всяком случае те, в которых я искал), не дают информации о происхождении такого распространённого слова как «ответственность».

В [Викисловаре сказано](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):

> Происходит от прил. ответственный и сущ. ответ, из праслав. *otъvětъ ...

В свою очередь «ответственный» [согласно тому же Викисловарю](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):

> Происходит от сущ. ответ, из от- + -вет, далее от праслав. *věti̯o ...

Значит «ответственность» происходит от слова «ответ».

Однако «ответ» в [Большом толковом словаре определяется как «ответственность»](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82):

> **ОТВЕТ,** -а; ***м.*** ...  **5. Ответственность** за совершённые действия, поступки. *Призвать к ответу кого-л. Быть в ответе за что-л. (нести ответственность). Держать о. за свои проступки. За всё в ответе (об ответственности каждого за общее дело).*

Из этого следует, что «ответственность» происходит от слова «ответ», которое в свою очередь значит «ответственность» — круг замкнулся.

---

В [статье](https://publikacia.net/archive/uploads/pages/2014_7_1/45.pdf) говорится:

> Во многих европейских языках слово «ответственность» восходит к
> латинскому глаголу «respondere», буквально означающему «обещать» или «давать взамен», а
> в более широком смысле — «отвечать». Абстрактное существительное от данного глагола,
> по-видимому, появилось не раньше второй половины XVIII столетия. Во всяком случае,
> одним из первых, кто использовал слово «responsibility» («ответственность») считается
> английский философ-моралист и правовед Иеремия Бентам (1748–1832), который в своем
> сочинении «Фрагмент о правлении» (1776) под «responsibility of governors»
> («ответственностью правителей») понимал их обязанность отвечать (отчитываться) перед
> гражданами за свои действия [см.: 2, p. 94, etc].
>
> *[[Аль-Ани Н.М. Ответственность и её классическая и неклассическая парадигмы. СПб НИУ ИТМО. Журнал: Актуальные проблемы гуманитарных и естественных наук. Номер: 7-1. Год: 2014.
> Страницы: 182-187. Издательство: Научное издательство «Институт стратегических исследований»](https://publikacia.net/archive/2014/7/1/45)].*

---

Можно ли в таком случае объяснить происхождение русского слова, как кальку с иностранного?

---

Так же хотелось бы получить разъяснение эволюции смысла, от слова «ответ» к, например:

> **ОТВЕТСТВЕННЫЙ,** ... **3.** Отличающийся высокоразвитым чувством долга, добросовестно относящийся к своим обязанностям. *О. человек.*
>
> [[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)]

Ведь если понимать под изначальным смыслом слова «ответственность» то, что описано в отрывке из статьи выше: обязанность отвечать, т. е. отчитываться за свои действия, то получается, что «ответственный» это просто тот, кто в прямом смысле отвечает на вопросы, касательно выполнения или не выполнения возложенной на него работы.

А сейчас это слово приобрело некий смысл морального качества. По какой логике пришли к такому значению слова?

Кроме того, слово «ответственный» ещё используется как:

> **3.** ... // Связанный с пониманием важности исполнения чего-л., необходимости добросовестно выполнить что- л. *О-ое отношение к делу.*
>
> [[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x)]

В таких значениях уже не идёт речь про дачу кому-либо каких-либо ответов на вопросы о проделанной работы, а понимается просто некое качество человека или его деятельности.

Comment: Во-первых, "ответственны" -- одно из значений слова "ответ", выделившееся в отдельное слово, ок, и что? Какое "замыкание круга"? Замыкание круга -- это сепульки как инструмент для сепуления, а сепуление как то, что делают сепульками. // Далее. Посмотрите первое значение суффикса "-ственн-" (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136477/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD) -- оно разъяснит вам, что означает слово "ответ-ственн-ный", если разобрать его на морфемы.

Comment: @Nektoid Да, одно из значений, но я выбрал подходящее по смыслу. От какого значения слово произошло по-вашему?

Comment: @Nektoid По приведенной ссылке: _«Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах прилагательных, которые обозначают признак или свойство, характеризующиеся тем или отношением к тому, что названо мотивирующим словом»_.  В случае, например, «ум» > «умственный» понятно, относящийся уму. Но «ответ» > «ответственный», получается, относящийся к «ответу». Тогда возникает вопрос: в каком значении тут слово «ответ»?

Comment: @Nektoid В [Викисловаре про суффикс -ств-](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2): _«при добавлении к основе прилагательного образует существительное со значением свойства ◆ равный → равенство»_. Как можно образовать свойство от слова «ответ»?

Comment: Я думаю, раз вы интересуетесь этимологией, то вам стоит освоить ряд соответствующих учебников и пособий, чтобы понимать, как этимология вообще устроена, какие принципы в основе и какие методы и как используются. (Гуглите "курс этимологии, список литературы".) Пока что ваши вопросы, уж извините, выглядят примерно как 'почему трава зелёная', а ответы вы хотите на высоком научном уровне.

Comment: @Nektoid Как я понял из вашей критики — ответа вы не знаете. В таком случае не стоит ничего писать вообще. На вопрос «почему трава зелёная» можно дать ответ очень даже научный. Можете почитать, если интересно [Почему трава зеленая?](https://postnauka.ru/faq/91854) И что вы находите ненормального в таком вопросе?

Comment: Если для вас ответ "трава зелёная, потому что хлорофиллы зелёные" норм, то на таком уровне как раз я ответ и дал. Чтобы понять более глубокий ответ, вам недостаёт знаний (например, вы выцепили по ссылке только слово "умственный" и не задались вопросом, от каких слов построены другие примеры: "женственный", "собственный"; даже, по-видимому, не знаете, что некогда существовало слово "ответство"). Я уж не говорю, что в своих изысканиях вы воспользовались неоконченной статьёй в Викисловаре и не узнали, что у суффикса "-ств-" выделяют по меньшей мере пять значений, а не два. Успехов вам.

Comment: @Nektoid Успехов я Вам тоже могу пожелать. Вы тратите слишком много времени на критику меня, а следовало бы либо дать ответ, либо вообще ничего не писать. То, что хлорофилл зелёный тоже имеет свои причины: он позволяет растениям получать энергию света путём фотосинтеза, при этом он поглощает в основном красные и синие длинны волн, а зелёные в основном отражает. То есть, грубо говоря, для получения энергии используются красные и синие волны, а зелёные — нет, они отражаются, и мы их видим.

Comment: @Nektoid Теперь насчёт того, что я там «выцепил». У меня написано _«В случае, например, „ум“ > „умственный“ понятно, относящийся уму»_. Вы понимаете слово «например»? Оно означает, что это частный случай, приводимый в пояснение. Я не могу разбирать в комментарии все слова в словарной статье. Вы можете взять другие слова и на примере их пояснить свою точку зрения, но вы этого не делаете, потому что ответа не знаете.

Comment: @Nektoid По дальнейшему тексту, где Вы «уже не говорите» и при этом говорите: мои изыскания я должен привести в соответствии с правилами сайта — это раз. Если б я всё знал, я вопроса бы не задавал, как и другие пользователи этого сайта, и существование сайта потеряло бы всякий смысл — это два.